# Running a headless Eclipse RCP Application without the osgi console

Tags: console, eclipse-rcp

i want to create a headless Eclipse RCP Application that can be started from console. Currently i'm using this parameter in the .ini file:

> -consoleLog

The problem is this opens an extra OSGI console which i don't want. Is there any way to supress the console and get the output in the original terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-consoleLog` doesn't open an OSGi console, which shows up as *osgi>*.  Only `-console` does that.

DO you mean it opens a second windows console (similar to cmd.exe) and you just want that to appear in your original cmd.exe window?

If that's the case, then you use `eclipsec.exe -consoleLog -application <whatever>` to launch.

Comment: basically you are right, but there is no eclipsec.exe in my Targetplatform. and the other problem is that PDE is not able to export with eclipsec.exe -> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=185207

Comment: ah, found the file in the deltapack!

Comment: @Paul Webster  how to create this eclipsec.exe for RCP application

Comment: It's part of the delta pack for windows RCP apps (it's not applicable to windows or mac)